# Find observable from input-field

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

When an input gets focus, I want to pop up a warning if the input is invalid.
The message is in the observable.

So given this code, how do I find the observable bound to it.

```
$(document).on("focus", "input.invalid", function(){
        console.log("ahaaaa!");
        //your code here
        //dig out observable from this and find the message
        //create element with class invalid-message and place it next to this
    }).on("blur", function(){
        $(".invalid-message").remove();
    });
```

I'm using knockout validation and I only want to show the error message when the field has focus. Other suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:
When I'm using dataFor:

```
    $(document).on("focus", "input.invalid", function(){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(ko.dataFor(this));
        ...
```

I get this in the console:

[image: Console screenshot]

The underlined observable is the one I'm after.

EDIT2:
I'm working around it like this:

```
    $(document).on("focus", "input.invalid", function(){
        var fieldName = $(this).attr("name");
        var errorMessage = ko.dataFor(this)[fieldName].error;
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ko.dataFor(this)
```

which will give you the observable of the current element.

For more details, look here:
[Using unobtrusive event handlers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I am unable to get the observable for the field. I get the parent (the observable for the entire form).

Comment: from what I see you get a SupplierObservable in which there is the supplierName obervable? So why you don't you get the needed obervable by: var neededObervable = ko.dataFor(this)().supplierName;

Comment: I am able to work around it by setting the name of the observable as the name of the field. But I hope it is not the only way.

Comment: yes, but inside the SupplierObservable there are several observables, each bound to an input field. Which one to pick each time.

Comment: Aha, now I got it! Yes, I suppose the best thing I can think of is getting the obervalbe by name,as you already noted. Something like: var neededObervable = ko.dataFor(this)()[this.getAttribute("name")];

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use Knockout's `event` binding to set up handlers for `focus` and `blur`? Your handlers will be called with the value of the input as their first parameter; no need to play around with jQuery.

Comment: you mean I will have to write data-bind="event : { focus : functionX, blur : functionY}" on every field? No thanks. If I misunderstand, please tell me. :)

Comment: You could create a custom binding: in fact the Knockout documentation for custom bindings includes an example that's very close to what you want (under "Modifying observables after DOM events").

Comment: It still requires me to add a binding to every single input field. Or do I misunderstand it? I am writing a sort of library for my company and I want the validation to work without the user doing anything.